# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Tomcat 9 outside JVM

Tags: java, sql, tomcat9

I'm writing a messaging app as my final project for 12 grade and I have an error that I have no idea how to even approach. I disabled and re-enabled features of the web app one by one to see when the error occurs, and I observed that when I try to bring the active conversations that one user has, my server crashes. This doesn't happen constantly, it seems like random occurrences. Here is the error message by the server:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007034537d, pid=13536, tid=9944
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.10+8) (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE id1 = '1' OR id2 = '1' ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0;# 
CSELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = 16;
  [sqlite-3.30.1-03ac4057-b812-49a1-9a10-f02ba1c22986-sqlitejdbc.dll+0x537d]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\paRa\AppData\Local\Temp\\hs_err_pid13536.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

From what I saw on other posts, this error message should point where the error is located, in my case if I go to the specific lines where those SQL queries are executed, I have no error.

What it should be noted is that when I put a break point in the API of the `activeConversations` function, the server never crashes, so I was thinking that it had something to do with how much information is being handled. However, there isn't much information transferred at the moment since I don't have that much information in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation (outside of a bug in sqlite) is that the JVM is running the webserver with a lot of threads but the sqlite configuration is using single threaded mode and thus causing memory corruption.

Check that you are starting/configuring the sqlite with at least multi threaded mode.

https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: I wil check this right now, It will take a bit of time since I don't know how to configure it =). I'll let you know if this resolved my problem @AIBlue

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I want to mention that @AlBlue message was really helpful in resolving my problem. As he said my database (SQLite) was handling multiple requests at the same time, and so it crashed. Since I did not know how to configure sqlite to multi threading, I used a deffered object in jquery to make a function run after another. You can see what i used by clicking on this link: [Jquery Deffered Function](http://willmclean.net/calling-one-jquery-function-only-after-another-function-has-run/) (site is not seccured btw, so be carefull, I will also post the code down below in the case some of you do not want to access the site:

```
var functionOne = function() {

    var r = $.Deferred();

    // Do your whiz bang jQuery stuff here
    console.log('Function One');

    return r;

};

var functionTwo = function() {

    // Do your whiz bang jQuery stuff here
    console.log('Function Two');

};

// Now call the functions one after the other using the done method
functionOne().done( functionTwo() );
```

Again thank you to everyone for the answers! I am recent to this platform and I do not how this procedure works. Since my answer is a solution to my problem, and not to the error itself, then I should give the correct answer to @AlBlue correct? I'll update the answer once somebody comments. I want to give propper credit!

Edit: I read the tooltip of the button =))

Answer (score 0):

An access violation means that native code (in this case inside SQLite) is trying to access memory it is not allowed to access, this usually indicates a **bug** in that native library (or in another native component it is depending on). It is unlikely - though not impossible - the problem is in your own code.

As a first step, try to see if using a newer version of SQLite solves the problem. If that doesn't solve it, try to reduce the code necessary to reproduce the problem and report it either to the authors or SQLite or the SQLite JDBC driver you're using.

Comment: ok! i'll try and do that! thank you very much, I'll look into it!

Comment: I have a question :/. This might be a very dumb question but how do i run in DB Browser the correct version of SQLite, cause i have downloaded the newest version but i don't know how to run it:/ @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: @MateiAvram I don't have much experience with SQLite (to be honest, I think it is an odd choice for a web app), nor do I know SQLite DB Browser. Consider asking a new question.

Comment: I only chose SQLite because this is what i have been advised by my teacher. I researched a bit and saw that SQLite is not made for Client/Server applications. And this is how i stumbled upon SQLitening. The problem is I have to finish my application today and while i do not have so many more features to implement, I am concerned that I might not have enough time to switch between the two. It should be noted that I haven't researched enough at this point to see the differences between the two, and I am looking for that now.

Comment: For now anyway I will continue on finishing the features and will try and change this after I finish the project otherwise I might not meet my deadline. Thank you very much for the help! ^_^